# Can I set Lock mode to wait in Informix - JDBC - tomcat connection pooling?

Tags: java, informix

I am running a web application with Tomcat - JDBC  connection pooling with Informix database. How do I set lock mode to wait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also set the default lock time using the 'IFX_LOCK_MODE_WAIT' connection string property (for datasources use 'ds.setIfxIFX_LOCK_MODE_WAIT()')

More info here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_034.htm

so, for tomcat, if your datasource looks something like:

```
<Context path="/jspdemo" docBase="jspdemo" debug="0" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">
  <Resource name="jdbc/jspdemo" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="20" 
    maxIdle="10" maxWait="1000" username="informix"  password="mypasswd" 
    driverClassName="com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver" 
    url="jdbc:informix-sqli://mymachine:1526/stores_demo:INFORMIXSERVER=ol_myserver"/>
</Context>
```

just use:

```
<Context path="/jspdemo" docBase="jspdemo" debug="0" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">
  <Resource name="jdbc/jspdemo" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="20" 
    maxIdle="10" maxWait="1000" username="informix"  password="mypasswd" 
    driverClassName="com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver" 
    url="jdbc:informix-sqli://mymachine:1526/stores_demo:INFORMIXSERVER=ol_myserver;IFX_LOCK_MODE_WAIT=60;/>
</Context>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my environment the first SQL executed after obtaining db connection from pool is:

```
SET LOCK MODE TO WAIT 15
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I set this value via JDBC connection

Answer (score 0):

"How do I set this value via JDBC connection"

As per previous answers either pass it as a connection property or execute the SQL at the start of the connection.